# Combine hooks without using Provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm trying to combine several contexts that are feed with some async operations, in my app's pages.
I would like to combine these contexts without using the `Context.Provider`  because it could be verbose. For example,

```
<Route path="/discover">
  <MainContainer extraClass="discover-container" hasHeader={true}>
    <UserContext>
      <ContentContextProvider>
        <NotificationContext>
          <Discover />
        </NotificationContext>
      </ContentContextProvider>
    </UserContext>
  </MainContainer>
</Route>
```

In each of these Context I wrapper the child with the context. Fe,

```
import React from "react";
import useAllContent from "utils/hooks/useAllContent";

const ContentContext = React.createContext({});

export const ContentContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { allContent, setAllContents } = useAllContent([]);

  return (
    <ContentContext.Provider value={{ allContent, setAllContents }}>
      {children}
    </ContentContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ContentContext;
```

This works, but as I mentioned before is very verbose so i would like to use the Contexts like an objetcs to combine between them.
I tried:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { DataStore, Predicates } from "@aws-amplify/datastore";
import { Content } from "models";

const useAllContent = (initialValue) => {
  const [allContent, setContent] = useState(initialValue);

  const setAllContents = useCallback(async () => {
    const contents = await DataStore.query(Content, Predicates.ALL);
    setContent(contents);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (allContent === 0) setAllContents();
  }, [allContent, setAllContents]);

  return { allContent, setAllContents };
};

export default useAllContent;
```

```
import React from "react";
import useAllContent from "utils/hooks/useAllContent";

const { allContent, setAllContents } = useAllContent([]);
const ContentContext = React.createContext({ allContent, setAllContents });

export default ContentContext;
```

But I break the rule `× Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

How could i achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Combining instances of `React.Context` in the way you describe would require manipulating the values they contain. But there is no way to access the value of a `Context` without using its corresponding `Provider`. I sympathize with the dislike of verboseness, but it is unavoidable in this case.